# How to get user value back to Power Virtual Automate from Bot Framework Composer

Tags: botframework, powerapps, adaptive-cards, power-virtual-agents

I am creating a Power Virtual App bot and I am also using Bot framework Composer to display an Adaptive card that is meant to take user input from the Power Virtual App bot.

I'm unable to figure out a way around this and all the solutions I've come across don't have Adaptive Card involved.

I want this to work because I will need the user input to make API calls via Power Automate and display the results back to the user.

enter image description here

[image: Screenshot of the card menu]

[image: Screenshot of the flow in botframework]

Comment: I can't view the edits, can you add it as a comment please?

Comment: Those were just minor errors. You are new here that's why you are reacting like this. No problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to set the input / output properties on your Composer dialog. Once you have configured your output variables, you can assign values to them within Composer.

Here is a [link to an answer](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Bot-Extensibility/Pass-variable-from-Bot-Framework-back-to-PVA/m-p/1386788/highlight/true#M70) that was asked similar to this question.

Hope this helps.